# How can I replicate elasticsearch data to neo4j?

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, graphaware

I have a neo4j database and I have successfully used the graphaware neo4j2elastic plugin to replicate the data into elasticsearch. However, I would also like to replicate documents created in elasticsearch into neo4j.

When I create nodes in neo4j corresponding documents are created in elasticsearch. I would like to be able to index a document in elasticsearch and have a node automatically created in neo4j.

The documentation for [neo4j-to-elasticsearch](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch/) states (emphasis mine):

> GraphAware Elasticsearch Integration is an enterprise-grade **bi-directional** integration between Neo4j and Elasticsearch.

So I hoped it would work both ways but it doesn't seem to. I've seen other questions mention [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html) but as I understand it this requires me to script a solution, that at best could run on a schedule to import new data.

Ideally, I would like something that creates neo4j nodes as I index something. Is there anything that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Neo4j-To-Elasticsearch states also, just a couple of lines below, where the module for Elasticsearch is, however this will not create nodes in your database, rather it is for querying the graph using search.

I suggest you read carefully the README provided as well as our blog posts around the subject to understand what it does and what it doesnt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of the Elasticsearch  module but I understand that it won't replicate data from Elastic to neo4j.

The closest I've come to a solution is using elasticsearch watch to detect the ingest of new documents and then use a webhook action to create corresponding nodes in neo4j. 
This is a clunky, hacky solution but might work in my use case.